# How to use a "where not" clause with searchkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, elasticsearch, searchkick

I am using Searchkick with Elasticsearch to get products with a search term.

I am trying to add a `WHERE NOT` clause to it so it won't return any products with a `regular_price` that is null.

```
@products = Product.search(
        search,
        where: {
          regular_price: {
            not: "null" # I have also tried nil, both won't work
          }
        },
        page: params[:page],
        per_page: per_page,
      )
```

The search ignores my `WHERE NOT` clause.

I would also be grateful for some debugging tips for this.

Edit:

So I have tried to use the following but now it just returns every product that fits the search. Ignoring the `WHERE NOT` part of the search.

```
@products = Product.search(
        search,
        where: {
          regular_price: {
            _not: "null" 
          }
        },
        page: params[:page],
        per_page: per_page,
      )
```

`UPDATE:`

I have not found a solution to this issue and I moved on with a diffrent approach. By filtering out the products with a `regular_price` of 0.

Comment: According the [the README](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#querying), the syntax for a "where not" query is: `where: { _not: { regular_price: 'null' } }`. Did you try this?

Comment: I'm also a bit confused by your question -- Did you want to exclude products with a price of zero, or a null price? Zero and null are not the same thing. (For example, `null` might mean "contact dealer to get a quote", whereas `0` presumably means **"free"**.)

Comment: My products have a regular_price value and a price value. I want to exclude the products with a null value for regular_price from the search because those are for business customers only. I will try to use the _not as soon as I can.

Comment: My point was that the second line of your post says "...it won't return any products with a regular_price that is **0**", but your code indicates you want to exclude **null** values. I didn't know which you actually want, because your question is inconsistent.

Comment: Yes excuse me for the confusion. I want to exclude products that have the regular_price value of null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't found an answer yet. Because there aren't many products that I want to filter out with this query, I just filter them out while rendering.

Answer (score 2):

```
@products = Product.search(
    search,
    where: {
      regular_price: {
        _not: nil 
      }
    },
    page: params[:page],
    per_page: per_page,
  )
```

Just replace `"null"` with `nil` and it would filter out the products that don't have regular_price.